# Sencha Touch: Declaring Stores

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have 2 options to create the store and use it across my app but I can't decide which is best or why: 
I can either use:

```
Ext.regStore('CustomerList', {
```

and use

```
store:'CustomerList',
```

and

```
Ext.StoreMgr.get('CustomerList')
```

**OR**

```
HSA.stores.CustomerList = new Ext.data.Store({
```

and use:

```
HSA.stores.CustomerList
```

Which one is the best way to be handling stores and why (and in which case)?
cheers

Jason Rogers

Answer (score 0):

I use MVC with Sencha Touch and create/access my stores in the following manner:

```
Ext.regStore('Updates', { });

var updatesStore = Ext.getStore("Updates");
```

Note that when I am not using MVC, I create the store in the same manner but access it by using the app's namespace like so:

```
app.stores.updates.load();
```